# Failed to create a partition on Windows for a Dual Boot

Tags: partitioning

Used disk management to shrink the volume of my primary partition C drive, but it only allows me to shrink it by a couple dozen megabytes for an unallocated partition. I  tried turning off bitlocker and device encryption but it still doesn't allow me to shrink my C drive enough.

Comment: Are you using Windows tools to shrink partition? What version of Windows? If problems, try temporarily disabling system restore, pagefile, (in advanced settings in computer properties) and hibernate option (in power management). Don’t forget to turn them on back later.

Comment: I turned off System Restore and then was able to shrink the volume! Thanks for the competent advice, oldfred

Comment: I don't see the check mark to click to accept the answer.

Comment: You have to put an @ in front of the name to notify the person.  There is no answer (yet), so no way to accept it;^)  You can answer your own question, and accept it after  a bit.

Comment: @MaureenMoore The large gray checkmark to accept the answer is to the left and beside the answer. The checkmark changes color from gray to green when it is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Windows tools to shrink partition?
What version of Windows?

Be sure to have good backups before any system change. And create Windows repair/recovery flash drive, just in case. Best to have both Windows & Ubuntu repair tools current & available at all times.

If problems, try temporarily disabling system restore, pagefile, (in advanced settings in computer properties) and hibernate option (in power management). Don’t forget to turn them on back later.